# solving the equation to find variables.

Tags: problem-solving

I have an equation 
$M = P\left(\frac{J}{\left(1-\left(1+J\right)^{-N}\right)}\right)$

I am trying to solve it to find J but I am stuck at 
$\frac{P}{M} = \frac{\left(1 + J\right)^N - 1}{J(1+J)^N}$

can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't spend too much time on this, Wolfram Alpha says it is not possible to solve for $J$ as a function of $\frac PM$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. If one sets
$$
X=1+J
$$ then the given relation is
$$
\frac{P}M=\frac{X^N-1}{X-1}\cdot \frac1{X^N}
$$ that is
$$
\frac{P}M=\left(X^{N-1}+X^{N-2}+\cdots+1 \right)\cdot \frac1{X^N}
$$ or
$$
P \cdot X^N-M\cdot\left(X^{N-1}+X^{N-2}+\cdots+1 \right)=0.
$$ Finding $X$ in terms of parameters $M$ and $P$ is solving an equation of $N$-th degree which is handled *[numerically](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Numerical_Methods/Equation_Solving#Newton-Raphson)* rather than *symbolically*.